# Filter Aggregated Data Using Elastic Search 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have a posts index whose data looks something like this:

```
{
  "title": "Some Recipe",
  "book_id": 123,
  "content": "A list of ingredients",
  "tags": ["apple", "cinnamon", "honey"]
}
```

I'd like to have a query that retrieves all of tags that start with a given phrase and the number of posts that contain that tag.

So far, I've tried the following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "book_id": 123
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "filter": { "prefix": { "tags": "app" } },
      "aggs":   {
        "tags" : { "terms": { "field": "tags" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I believe it is returning all of the tags in all of the documents and the number of documents that have a tag which starts with `app`.

Is it possible to have it pull back all the tags that begin with `app`, in this case `apple`, and the number of documents that have that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `terms` aggregation allows you to [filter the values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) of the terms using the `include` setting. Try with this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "book_id": 123
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "filter": { "prefix": { "tags": "app" } },
      "aggs":   {
        "tags" : { 
          "terms": { 
            "field": "tags",
            "include": "app.*"            <--- add this
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```